# FTP - `Name or service not know`

Tags: ftp, connection, lan

I have an app, on my iphone, which allows me to transfer songs too and from my linux desktop via ftp. The app indicates that the host address is `192.168.0.4` and the port to be used is `5021`. I can connect fine to the device from filezilla but when I try to connect via the command line it fails with the error mentioned in the title.

The command i'm using is `ftp 192.168.0.4:5021` but it fails. I'm totally stumped. When I search for help on the internet the answer is to simply do what I've done already.

Does anyone have an any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ftp` command does not support the `:5021` syntax for port numbers. Instead, there must be another way.

With some FTP clients, you can use a `-P` command line option:

```
ftp -P 5021 192.168.0.4
```

With others, you need to put the port number after the host address with a *space*:

```
ftp 192.168.0.4 5021
```

Use `man ftp` to see which yours supports.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The -P parameter is not recognised, the -p parameter indicates an invalid argument and without the argument it simply refuses again. There doesn't appear to be any alternatives the syntax stated is `ftp [..options..] [host [port]]`

Comment: Your Linux must have a different ftp program. Both the one on FreeBSD and the one on Mac OS X support `-P`. But yours says that you can put the port number after the host name, with a *space*, not a colon. Try `ftp 192.168.0.4 5021`.

Comment: Thanks alot it works! I was trying it with square brackets like an idiot, basically everything i could think off except on its own. Your a super star lol

Comment: In man pages, the square brackets generally means it's an *optional* parameter, not that you would type the actual square brackets. So in your case, `[host [port]]` means you can specify no address, or just a host, or a host and a port.

Comment: cool, thanks for the tip :). I don't know why but all this command line stuff is like legal crack!

Answer (score 0):

add domain and ip to hosts file of you computer.

Comment: He's already trying to connect directly to an IP; this is clearly not a DNS issue and modifying the hosts file won't help.

Comment: I have meet the same problem. Neither ip or domain not work. untill I add domain and ip to the hosts file.